# Radio buttons used like a <select> dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use radio buttons styled like a fancy `select` dropdown—purely with CSS. It seems to work in every browser except Safari. I'm not sure how or why this code I found online works at all, nor do I have a clue why it won't work with Safari on macOS. The problem is that the expanded list doesn't collapse after selecting an option, in Safari. Pretty interesting stuff.

Any suggestions on how to get it working in Safari...or on any other improvements would be appreciated.

```css
div.select {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   position: relative;
   width: 350px;
   height: 40px;
}

div.select label {
   order: 2;
   border-top: #222 solid 1px;
   background-color: #E5E5E5;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   padding: 0 30px 0 10px;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 40px;
   pointer-events: none;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   z-index: 1;
}

div.select label:hover {
   background-color: #FF595C;
}

div.select:focus label {
   position: relative;
   pointer-events: all;
}

input {
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   left: -99999px;
}

input:checked+label {
   order: 1;
   border-top: none;
   background-color: #FF595C;
   color: white;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}

input:checked+label:before {
   content: '';
   background-color: #050505;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
}

input:checked+label:after {
   content: '';
   background-color: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   top: 17px;
   right: 14px;
   width: 0.8em;
   height: 0.5em;
   clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
   z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
 <div class="select" tabindex="1">
    <input name="career" type="radio" id="c1" checked><label for="c1">Web Design</label>
    <input name="career" type="radio" id="c2"><label for="c2">Web Development</label>
    <input name="career" type="radio" id="c3"><label for="c3">SEO</label>
    <input name="career" type="radio" id="c4"><label for="c4">UI / UX Designer</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Safari on what system?

Comment: macOS Monterey 12.4

Comment: ...Safari v15.5

Comment: Same buggy behavior on Safari for iOS.

Comment: It seems that the tabindexed div is keeping its focus when a child is focused in Safari. I don't honestly know which is the correct behavior.

Comment: Same bug exists in Safari v15.6 on macOS 12.5.

Answer (score -1):

There are some CSS codes that doesn't work on safari, especially the old versions. People uses -webkit or -ms in front of their css property to make them work on older version of safari and other browsers.

Comment: Answers of the type "This might be related, who knows, try it, or else maybe not" are never good answers. If you don't know a real, specific and concrete answer, then it is better not to answer (or better to delete your answer in this case).

Comment: v15.5 is the latest. Also, I'll be using a post processor to add vendor prefixes before publishing pages to my static site.